# Android launcher wrapper java activity

Tags: android, terminal, launcher

I am making a android launcher that is basically a wrapper for another app. In the current code, it displays a black activity window then goes to the other app. How can I get it just to launch the other app?

StartTerm.java (the main activity's java file)

```
package tk.jordynsblog.terminal.launcher;

import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class StartTerm extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start_term);
}

@Override
protected void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();
    try{
        Intent i = new Intent("jackpal.androidterm.RUN_SCRIPT");
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        i.putExtra("jackpal.androidterm.iInitialCommand", "echo 'Hi there!'");
        startActivity(i);
    }catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Jackpals Android terminal emulator is not installed.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }

 }
}
```

The blank activity

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Step #1: Use `Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar`, to have a UI-less activity.

Step #2: Get rid of `setContentView()`.

Step #3: Move your current code from `onStart()` into `onCreate()`, after `super.onCreate()`.

Step #4: Call `finish()` at the end of `onCreate()`, as this activity is no longer useful once you have started the third-party activity.

Comment: Thanks, That work perfectly. Now i just have to figure out how to mark this question as solved.

Comment: @JordynCarattini: There should be the outline of a checkmark on the left side of the answer. Tap that, and it will turn green, marking the answer as accepted.